# How to set value in multiple select option in FORM in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hmtl:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="loaisanpham">Loại Sản Phẩm</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="idLoaisp" id="idLoaisp" ng-model="idLoaisp"  ng-required=true>
     <option ng-repeat="loaisanpham in loaisanphams | orderBy: 'tenLoaisp'" value="{{loaisanpham.idLoaisp}}">{{loaisanpham.tenLoaisp}}</option>
   </select><br> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phuong">Phường</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="idVungxa" id="idVungxa" ng-model="idVungxa"  ng-required=true>
      <option ng-repeat="vungxa in vungxas | orderBy: 'tenVungxa'" value="{{vungxa.idVungxa}}">{{vungxa.tenVungxa}}</option>
   </select><br>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("idLoaisp").value = track.loaisanpham.idLoaisp;
document.getElementsById("idVungxa").value = track.vungxa.idVungxa;
```

Just **idLoaisp** show value in html and **idVungxa** not show.

I do not understand why it is not displayed. Help me. Tks all

Answer (score 0):

Assign your value to the $scope in your controller.

$scope.idVungxa = track.loaisanpham.idLoaisp;

Answer (score 0):

In plain HTML5 you would set the option as "selected":

like this:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b" selected>b</option>
  <option value="c" selected>c</option>
</select>
```

There might be a different way to do it in Angular, but if this helps, you can use

```
<option [attr.selected]="boolean" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute `"value"` in the html options and set the value to the model, you have `ng-model="idLoaisp"` and `ng-model="idVungxa"` in the view so I guess in your **controller** you have that variables to store the values of the item selected, models are double binding that means you can also set the value to that model.

```
$ctrl.idLoaisp = track.loaisanpham.idLoaisp
$ctrl.idVungxa = track.vungxa.idVungxa
```

Comment: Tks U. But When when I change new option. it can't get value

Comment: you don't need use javascript like document.GetElementById, you have access to that value with the model variable that you are using, I'm not sure that you're using Angular in the proper way.

Comment: check this reference https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select